# How to get value from validator error in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need to get value from validator error 'minLength' to pass it into message.

Html:

```
 <div class="mt-2" *ngIf="ngControl.control.errors?.minlength">
            {{ 'DATA.form_messages.minLength' | translate: { length: //Value from error// } }}
        </div>
```

[image]

```
 <div>{{ngControl.control.getError('minlength') | json}}</div>
```

Above i'm displaying error which i'm interested in. But how can i get value from it?
I've tried something like this

ngControl.control.getError('minlength')['requiredLength'].value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove `.value` part so it will become

`ngControl.control.getError('minlength')['requiredLength']`

and will work